# django: use model methods without create instance

Tags: django, model, instance

I have a Model `Product` with business methods. My model contains relationship with Models `Item` and `Dealer`.

Let's say my `Product` is serialized as / can be created from:

```py
{
    "name": "productA",
    "items": [2,3,13],
    "dealer": [1,2]
}
```

I can for instance run `Product.simulate()`:

````py
class Product(Models):
    ....
    def simulate(self):
        ```dummy function to illustrate```
        return sum(i.price for i in self.items.all()) / len(i.dealer.all())
````

I would like to be able to compute `Product.simulation` with values in a dictionnary without creating `Product` instance. I have multiple `signals` and batch operation on `Product` Model I dont want to run on the only for simulation objects.

I could create a `for_simulation` attribute  on `Product` and specify on my signals / batch operation to don't run on those instances but it seems do lead to duplicate code and be forgotten on some signals / batch.

On the other hand, I could rewrite all my methods in `Product`, `Item`, `Dealer` to work with `dict` as input but there's a lot of them.

Is there a better way to achieve my goal ? Ideally I would like to be able to do something like:

```py
p = Product({
    "name": "productA",
    "items": [2,3,13],
    "dealer": [1,2]
})
p.simulation()
```

I cannot: my instances need to be saved to build relationships.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `simulate` method to your question. Is the reason your instances need to be saved that you run DB queries in the method?

Comment: done, this is the reason yes